# Framerate problem when saving video using gstreamer

Tags: video, frame, gstreamer

I am writing a program that stabilizes an input video and then save it to a video file using gstreamer. The pipeline I used is:

```
appsrc name=mySrc ! video/xraw,width=1920,height=1072,framerate=25/1,format=I420 ! avenc_mpeg4 bitrate=800000 max-threads=4 max-bframes=10 ! video/mpeg ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=
```

Each frame after being processed by the stabilization algorithm will be put into the saving pipeline at the rate of 10 fps (processing time is 100 ms). The problem is, although the saving framerate is set to 25 fps in the pipeline, the stored video is always played back at framerate of 10fps by default (I use VLC).

So, is the any parameters I missed that I could not configured the framerate I wanted?

Any help is highly appreciate

Comment: check if you could use the element [videorate](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-videorate.html) to increase your frame rate.

Comment: How do you generate the buffers that your appsrc pushes into the pipeline? Do you set DTS/PTS timestamps in these?

Comment: As **vk_gst** already suggested try to use *videorate* after your *appsrc* eg. appsrc name=mySrc ! videorate ! video/xraw,width=1920,height=1072,framerate=25/1,format=I420 ! etc.. 

Based on your capsfilter I'm guessing you are also missing *videoscale* and/or *videoconvert*, but in depends on your appsrc format ofcause. 
eg appsrc ! videoconvert ! videorate ! videoscale ! video/xraw,width=1920,height=1072,framerate=25/1,format=I420 ! etc..